# Google Earth api get coordinates

Tags: google-earth-plugin, kmz

here goes a simple question:
I've got a showKmz() function which receives an URL belonging to a KML/KMZ file and which goes straight ward to a fetchkml() method, after that it gets appended to my Google Earth instance.
Now I want to recover the coordinates of this fetched KML/KMZ file and use them to immediatelly after load a custom ico I want to put exactly on the same location of the KML/KMZ file I fetched.
The reason for that is that I want to show this files on Google Earth with their clicable icon despite of whatever icon those KML/KMZ could have by default...

Does anybody knows a way to either achieve the goal of retrieving the coordinates or even better: a more direct way to make this custom icon superposing I want?

Thanks in advance!!

Bye!!

Answer (score 0):

From here 
http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/kml.html

When getting a KML/Z file with fetchKml, you have in the callback an option to interact with the KMLFeatures you've obtained before appending them to the globe. There could be several items in that file which have coordinates, as well as several icons. So it sounds like you want to get the features, iterate over them, and insert an IconStyle for each (or replace existing IconStyle) to have it render with the Icon you want. You don't have to place a new feature at the same location as the existing ones.